# Android: Workmanager CoroutineWorker is always failing

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

My current problem is, that my Workmanager is always failing, but I don't know why. Actually, I don't even want to use a Workmanager but I didn't know a better way to cancel my Coroutine when the network is lost or when there never was a network.

What I am trying to do: Check if the network is available -> Download Collection from Cloud Firestore -> Show Progressbar -> Download Succeed -> Show List. I already managed to do this without workmanager with coroutines (without the check of network availability)

How it is currently: `Toast "Enqueue"` -> `Progress Bar` -> `Toast "Failed"`

### DocumentWorker

```
class DocumentWorker @WorkerInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    private val firebaseEntity: DocumentFirebaseRepository,
    private val documentDao: DocumentDao,
    private val networkMapper: DocumentNetworkMapper,
    private val cacheMapper: DocumentCacheMapper
): CoroutineWorker(context, params) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

        // Get Data from Cloud Firestore and map it to a DocumentCacheEntity to insert it to the database
        val documentEntityList: List<DocumentFirebaseEntity> = firebaseEntity.getAllDocuments()
        val documentCacheList: List<DocumentCacheEntity> = networkMapper.mapFromEntityList(documentEntityList)

        documentDao.insert(documentCacheList)

        //  Get the inserted list from the DAO and map it to Documents
        val cachedDocumentEntities: List<DocumentCacheEntity> = documentDao.getList()
        val documents: List<Document> = cacheMapper.mapFromEntityList(cachedDocumentEntities)

        // Convert List<Documents> to WorkData Object. Is this the correct way? I don't know...
        val data = workDataOf("documents" to documents)
        return Result.success(data)
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class DocumentViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DocumentWorker>()
        .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
        .build()

    val workInfo: LiveData<WorkInfo> = WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(work.id)


    fun setStateEvent(documentStateEvent: DocumentStateEvent) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            when (documentStateEvent) {
                is DocumentStateEvent.GetDocumentEvent -> {
                    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(work)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DocumentsFragment(private val documentListAdapter: DocumentListAdapter) : Fragment() {
    private val documentViewModel: DocumentViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        subscribeToWorker()
        documentViewModel.setStateEvent(DocumentStateEvent.GetDocumentEvent)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentDocumentsBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_documents, container, false).apply {
            adapter = documentListAdapter
        }.root
    }

    private fun subscribeToWorker() {
        documentViewModel.workInfo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            when(it.state) {
                WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED -> requireContext().toast("ENQUEUED")
                WorkInfo.State.RUNNING -> displayProgressBar(true)
                WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> {
                    displayProgressBar(false)
                    // Here I want to get my List<Document> and submit it to my ListAdapter...
                    documentListAdapter.submitList(it.outputData.getString("documents") as MutableList<Document>)
                }
                WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED -> {
                    requireContext().toast("BLOCKED")
                    displayProgressBar(false)
                }
                WorkInfo.State.FAILED -> {
                    requireContext().toast("FAILED")
                    displayProgressBar(false)
                }
                WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED -> {
                    requireContext().toast("CANCELLED")
                    displayProgressBar(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### App

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
    @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration =
        Configuration.Builder().setWorkerFactory(workerFactory).build()
}
```

If there is a better way of doing all this WITHOUT a Workmanager (e.g. manually checking the network state and cancelling a coroutine if the network is lost), then please tell me!

I appreciate every help, thank you

### EDIT

Okay, I found the error, here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key documents has invalid type class java.util.ArrayList
        at androidx.work.Data$Builder.put(Data.java:830)
        at com.example.app.data.models.validator.DocumentWorker.doWork(DocumentWorker.kt:42)
        at com.example.app.data.models.validator.DocumentWorker$doWork$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:11)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

And this might be the error:  `val data = workDataOf("documents" to documents)`

Comment: For your case WorkManager can be the best solution also if this download needs to start also when your app is in the background.
When you say that WorkManager is always failing, what error are you getting?
Keep in mind that to have a different constructor signature you need to use a WorkerFactory: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/customizing-workmanager-fundamentals-fdaa17c46dd2

Comment: Okay, I will look at the WorkerFactory, but to make on clear: The download does NOT need to start when the app is in the background. The download should start like this: User navigates to Fragment X, fragment X notifies ViewModel, ViewModel downloads stuff, ViewModel notifies Fragment X, END. How can I see what error message I am getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I have managed to solve my problem! As stated out above, it is (unfortunately) not possible to put a `List<Document>` inside a Workmanager inputData. So I came up with this solution:

### Workmanager

```
class DocumentWorker @WorkerInject @Singleton constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted params: WorkerParameters,
    private val firebaseEntity: DocumentFirebaseRepository,
    private val documentDao: DocumentDao,
    private val networkMapper: DocumentNetworkMapper,
): CoroutineWorker(context, params) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        // Get Data from Cloud Firestore and map it to a DocumentCacheEntity to insert it to the database
        val documentEntityList: List<DocumentFirebaseEntity> = firebaseEntity.getAllDocuments()
        val documentCacheList: List<DocumentCacheEntity> = networkMapper.mapFromEntityList(documentEntityList)
        documentDao.insert(documentCacheList)

        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class DocumentViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val documentDB: DocumentDao,
    private val cacheMapper: DocumentCacheMapper
    //private val documentRepository: DocumentRepository,
) : ViewModel() {
    // Save State and Document List in a Livedata Object that can be observed from the fragment
    private val _documentDataState: MutableLiveData<Status<List<Document>>> = MutableLiveData()
    val documentState: LiveData<Status<List<Document>>> get() = _documentDataState

    // Build the OnetimeWorkRequest
    private val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DocumentWorker>()
        .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
        .build()

    // Get the workInfo asFlow to observer it in the viewModel
    private val workInfo: Flow<WorkInfo> = WorkManager.getInstance(context).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(work.id).asFlow()

    fun setStateEvent(documentStateEvent: DocumentStateEvent) {
        when (documentStateEvent) {
            is DocumentStateEvent.GetDocumentEvent -> {
                // Here we Enqueue the Workmanager
                WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(work)

                // Now we will observe (collect) the workInfo
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    workInfo.collect {
                        when(it.state) {
                            WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED -> _documentDataState.postValue(Status.loading())
                            WorkInfo.State.RUNNING -> _documentDataState.postValue(Status.loading())
                            WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> {
                                // Document loaded successfully into db, so get it from there and post it to the livedata
                                val documentCacheEntityList = documentDB.getList()
                                val documentList = cacheMapper.mapFromEntityList(documentCacheEntityList)
                                _documentDataState.postValue(Status.success(documentList))
                            }
                            WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED -> _documentDataState.postValue(Status.failed("No Internet Connection"))
                            WorkInfo.State.FAILED -> _documentDataState.postValue(Status.failed("No Internet Connection"))
                            WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED -> _documentDataState.postValue(Status.failed("Loading cancelled"))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If there is a better way, then tell me. But this should work for now! The only problem I currently have is, that I want to return `Result.failed` when the Constraints are not fullfied within 5 seconds.

### Edit

I've made a function that `converts` the Result of the Workinfo to my own Status result.

```
suspend inline fun observerWorkerState(workInfFlow: Flow<WorkInfo>): Flow<Status<Unit>> = flow {
    workInfFlow.collect {
        when (it.state) {
            WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED -> emit(Status.loading<Unit>())

            WorkInfo.State.RUNNING -> emit(Status.loading<Unit>())

            WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> emit(Status.success(Unit))

            WorkInfo.State.BLOCKED -> emit(Status.failed<Unit>("Workmanager blocked"))

            WorkInfo.State.FAILED -> emit(Status.failed<Unit>("Workmanager failed"))

            WorkInfo.State.CANCELLED -> emit(Status.failed<Unit>("Workmanager cancelled"))
        }
    }
}
```